# Which of the following statements is not equvalent to remaining ones?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

Suppose $\vec{V}=p(x,y)\hat{i}+q(x,y) \hat{j}$ is a continuously differentiable vector field defined in a donmain D in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Which of the following statements is **NOT** equivalent to the remaining ones?

(a) There exists a function $\phi (x,y)$ such that $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}=p(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}= q(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in D$

(b)$\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}$

(c)$\oint_{C} \vec V.d\vec r=0$ for every piecewise smooth closed curve C in D

(d) The differential $pdx+qdy $ is exact in D

**My try**

Let **(a)** is holds i.e.

$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}=p(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}= q(x,y)$

$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y \partial x}=\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} \ and\   \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x \partial y}=\frac{\partial q}{\partial x} $

Thus $(a)\Rightarrow(b)$

$(b)\Rightarrow (d)$
Therefore $(a)\Rightarrow (b)\Rightarrow (d)\Rightarrow (a)$

Now let statement (c) holds then there  $\vec V=\bigtriangledown  \phi$

Which implies all the above statements .

**Anyone can tell me which is not equivalent to remaining ones?**

**Image of exact question**
[image]

Comment: @PaulSinclair sorry it was typing mistake i am going to correct it. Please give me hint which is not equvalent to remaining ones

Comment: By your arguments, you have not yet shown that the others imply (c). But that is not the problem, as (d) implies (c) by the FTC. What you need to do is look very carefully at the conditions on the theorems you used to show (c)⇒(a)⇒(b)⇒(d)⇒(a). Are you sure that those conditions are satisfied in every case?

Comment: @PaulSinclair can you explain it further or u can make correction in my answer. Actually this question was asked in IIT Exam and i dont know what is correct answer

Comment: No. I expect you to pull out your references and READ the conditions on the theorems you cited. Think about them. Do they always hold in the situation here?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I know when a holds then b and d always  holds but I have doubt on only statement c

Comment: If you choose to continue ignoring the advice that I've given you twice now, there isn't much point in my saying anything more.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thank you for your time. I did all what I know. You did not explain it well.

Comment: These all look equivalent, are you sure the problem is copied correctly?

Comment: @yoshi yes the problem is copied correctly. I am going share its image

Comment: @yoshi now you can see exact question. But i did not get it what paul sinclair wants to explain